# public GC storage access fails with Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to access Sentinel2 public data as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-datasets

That document says:
"By contrast, accessing public data with a Cloud Storage API link does not require authentication."

However I'm getting the following error:
"com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."
I'm using Java API:

storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()

blob = storage.get(BlobId.of("bucketName", "objectName"))

Does anyone know how to download those files using Java API?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sentinel-2 bucket, `gcp-public-data-sentinel-2`, does not allow unauthenticated, anonymous listing (although you should be able to [browse it](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/33/U/UP/?_ga=2.186879659.240071494.1650921170-250098428.1644256017) while logged in as any account). Instead, the object `index.csv.gz` inside the bucket contains a listing of the contents which you may access. Individual objects can be downloaded anonymously and have a fairly lengthy file path, for example:

https://storage.googleapis.com/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/04/E/CR/S2B_MSIL1C_20190301T202209_N0207_R042_T04ECR_20190301T212521.SAFE/GRANULE/L1C_T04ECR_A010364_20190301T202210/IMG_DATA/T04ECR_20190301T202209_B01.jp2

Answer (score 0):

The object needs to be publicly readable in order to access it anonymously, and that error indicates the object you're trying to read is not publicly readable.